# Updating based on intermediate query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy and am curious how I would conduct the following `UPDATE`.

I'm using SQL Expression Language and my version of SQLAlchemy is `1.3.16`. I wrote a query that returns [after some filtering and such] the following two columns of a larger table I'll call `my_table`.

```
+--------------+-----+
|team_member_id|id   |
+--------------+-----+
|3738          |7172 |
|2752          |1016 |
|3738          |7173 |
|3738          |7174 |
|3738          |7175 |
|3738          |7176 |
|3738          |7178 |
|3738          |7177 |
|140           |6679 |
|3568          |7221 |
|3568          |7220 |
...
```

There's a third column (`final_col`) of `my_table` that I'd like to update based on these two columns.

Basically, for each `(team_member_id, id)` pair above, I'd like to set the row's `final_col` value to be the `team_member_id` value. `id` stays the same; it's just the primary key.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found once possible solution in the form of `bindparam`.

```py
    update_executed_by = my_table.update().where(my_table.c.id == bindparam('_id')).values(
        final_col=bindparam('_team_member_id'))
    bound_params = [{'_team_member_id': row[0], '_id': row[1]} for row in session.execute(get_team_members)]
    session.execute(update_executed_by, bound_params)
```